# Why does this dapper query return null?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, dapper

I have a mysql statement that I am passing to the dapper query method and it is returning a null object.  I have created a POCO class to hold the returned result.  I tested the query directly through a sql editor and it returned a result.  Here is the code:

```
public ViewEmail GetViewEmail(string xId, int headerId)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM ViewEmail " +
                     "WHERE Header_id = @Header_id " +
                     "AND x_id= '@x_id'";

        var viewEmail = connection
            .Query<ViewEmail>(sql, new { Header_id = HeaderId, x_id = xId })
            .SingleOrDefault();

        return viewEmail;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove the quotes around `@x_id`

Comment: @haim770 - Thanks. That was it, but it is a bit confusing.  In MySql, I thought you had to put quotes around strings, for example, in a where clause. Does Dapper take care of this for you?

Comment: @xaisoft  `@x_id` is not a string.  It's a parameter that will contain a string.

Comment: @xaisoft, Using **Prepared Statements**, the actual parameters are appended server-side. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: as an aside if you declare the sql parameters as exactly the same as the method parameters you do not need to assign in the anonymous type. you could just use "new {xId, headerId}" so long as you make sure that the sql reads "WHERE Header_id = @headerId AND x_id = @xId"

Comment: Why `Header_id = HeaderId` ? Why not `Header_id = headerId` ?

Comment: @haim770 - If you put an answer, I  can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using **Prepared Statements**, no need to wrap the parameter with `'`. Try this instead:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM ViewEmail " +
             "WHERE Header_id = @Header_id " +
             "AND x_id= @x_id";
```

See [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)